# Deleting xml node in PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xmltype

How can I remove a node from xmltype using PL/SQL? Example:

```
<people>
   <person>
      <personNO>1</personNO>
   </person>
   <person>
      <personNO>2</personNO>
   </person>
</people>
```

I try to remove whole node person if /people/person/personNO is 1. My xml document is in the l_xml xmltype variable. So far I've got:

```
SELECT deletexml(l_xml, '/people/person[personNO="1"]')
INTO l_xml
FROM dual;
```

It doesn't seem to work at all. Can you please suggest any solution?

Answer (score 4):

define "doesn't work at all" as it will work just fine:

(tested on 10.2.0.4 + 11.2.0.3)

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_xml xmltype;
  3  begin
  4
  5    l_xml := xmltype.createXML('<people>
  6     <person>
  7        <personNO>1</personNO>
  8     </person>
  9     <person>
 10        <personNO>2</personNO>
 11     </person>
 12  </people>');
 13
 14    select deletexml(l_xml, '/people/person[personNO="1"]')
 15      into l_xml
 16      from dual;
 17
 18    dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getstringval());
 19  end;
 20  /
<people><person><personNO>2</personNO></person></people>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

so the whole person node for person no = 1 was deleted. if you intended to wipe out every  node if personNO 1 existed in any of them, then you want to set the xpath to `/people/person[../person/personNO="1"]`

Comment: That's weird, becouse by "doesn't work at all" i meant "does completly nothing". For me that piece of code did not give the desired output.

Comment: @Jandrejc - doesn't give the desired output, or doesn't give any output? Do you have server output turned on so you see the `dbms_output`? (`set serveroutput on` in SQL*Plus)

Comment: Doesn't give desired output. It gives me original xml, with node which was supposed to be removed.

Comment: @Jandrejc that whould suggest a bug that you need Oracle support to look at. what oracle version are you on? i assume your real XML does not use namespaces, because if it does, you need to declare those in order for the xpath to match the node correctly.